# Android universal splash screen for multiple devices

Tags: android, imageview, splash-screen

I need to support multiple screens with the app. The app is a web app and the only native part is splash screen. I have a bundle of images with the following sizes:
xlarge (xhdpi): 640x960
large (hdpi): 480x800
medium (mdpi): 320x480
small (ldpi): 240x320

In case of wvga854 I have blank spaces on the top/bottom of the screen. I've solved it by creating drawable-normal-long-hdpi. If I want my app to support most of the screens and tablets ([official reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) then I need to create folders for all possible combinations, am I right? In that case what would be the names of those folders?

Comment: If the splash screen has a solid background color, then you could just make the background of the imageview that solid color.

Comment: Unfortunately not... 9patch could not be aplied as well(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already mentioned the correct article for this problem. There is written:

```
res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
res/drawable-xxhdpi/my_icon.png
```

Additional you could add normal-long like you said (but I don't think this is necessary):

```
res/drawable-normal-long-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-normal-long-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-normal-long-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
res/drawable-normal-long-xxhdpi/my_icon.png
```

Also you need to consider if you maybe create folders for different orientations (land, port)

Edit: You should stick with Xoxols answer: android:scaleType should do the trick to get rid of gaps on top and bottom of the screen.

Comment: What about those ones:1536x1152, 1920x1152, 1920x1200 for hdpi and extra large screens? If I don't add normal-long then I see the background gaps on the top and bottom(

Comment: Maybe you should consider adding a "scaleType" like xoxol mentions. This should do the trick to get rid of the gaps on the top and bottom of the screen

Comment: will create long folders and put scaleType to cover all the cases

Comment: seems like it's working. the other usefull link: http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html to find the list of users/devices so you can decide what to support

Answer (score 1):

maybe scaling for your images? 
`android:scaleType` for example

Comment: So if I put 480x800 in the hdpi folder the image will look weird 480x854?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Pandrei i didn't have enough reputation for comment

Comment: @Nick maybe. this feature dependent from your parameter of scaleType

Comment: @xoxol_89 in that case, please rephrase your answer to look like an answer, not a comment or question.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my blog. Maybe it helps to clear things up. http://objectofclasshuman.blogspot.de/2014/04/android-user-interface.html

Additional use flexable layouts like relative layout and imageview with scaletype=fitcenter